# button to perform search with onclick in react

Tags: reactjs, button

what I want is to perform a search with the corresponding validation through the button search.
How can I make my button when pressed perform the search.

Comment: function Search() {

const [user, setUser]= useState([])

const URL ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'


    const showData = async () => {
        const respuesta = await fetch(URL)
        const data = await respuesta.json()
        setUser(data)
    }
   

    useEffect(()=>{
        showData()
    }, [])

Comment: const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const isValidDato = /^[a-z A-Z 0-9 .]+$/;

  const validateDato = (value) => {
    if (!isValidDato.test(value)) {
      setValid(false);
    } else {
      setValid(true);
    }
  };

  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    validateDato(e.target.value);
  }

Comment: return (
    <div className='busqueda'>
        <form className='Form'>
            <input className={`${valid ? "success" : "error"}`} maxLength="4" onChange={onChange} value={inputValue}/>
            <button type='submit' className={`${valid ? "success" : "error"}`}>Buscar</button>
        </form>
        <table className='styled-table'>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Empresa</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

Comment: { user.map( (user) => ( 
                <tr key={user.id}>
                    <td>{user.name}</td>
                    <td>{user.username}</td>
                    <td>{user.phone}</td>
                    <td>{user.company.name}</td>
                </tr>
                ))}
            
        </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet.

```
//hook to store query params
const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);

const handleFilter = (filter) => {
  filters.includes(filter)
    ? setFilters(filters.filter((value) => value !== filter))
    : setFilters(filters.concat(filter));
};


return(
    <div>
         //search field
         <input
            onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Search by phone number"
         />

         <button onClick={handleFilter}>Search</button>
    </div>

)
```